# duplicate symbols for architecture arm64 related to SDWebImage

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors, arm64

I know this one has been asked but i have read through the other questions and answers but I'm not seeing the issue in my project. Here is a snippet from the log. I think i have a duplicate something related to `SDWebImage` but i do not understand what this log is telling me. Can anyone see the problem?

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.orientation in:
    /Users/Daddio/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPPNAME-fpqubbtwwhfsgegevxpimtzqzhqb/Build/Intermediates/MYAPPNAME.build/Debug-iphoneos/MYAPPNAME.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SDWebImageDownloaderOperation-AD8E43D0E4994A5B.o
    /Users/Daddio/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPPNAME-fpqubbtwwhfsgegevxpimtzqzhqb/Build/Intermediates/MYAPPNAME.build/Debug-iphoneos/MYAPPNAME.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SDWebImageDownloaderOperation-4D62FB959721E071.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SDWebImageDownloaderOperation._credential in:
    /Users/Daddio/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPPNAME-fpqubbtwwhfsgegevxpimtzqzhqb/Build/Intermediates/MYAPPNAME.build/Debug-iphoneos/MYAPPNAME.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SDWebImageDownloaderOperation-AD8E43D0E4994A5B.o
    /Users/Daddio/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPPNAME-fpqubbtwwhfsgegevxpimtzqzhqb/Build/Intermediates/MYAPPNAME.build/Debug-iphoneos/MYAPPNAME.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SDWebImageDownloaderOperation-4D62FB959721E071.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SDWebImageDownloaderOperation._imageData in:
    /Users/Daddio/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPPNAME-fpqubbtwwhfsgegevxpimtzqzhqb/Build/Intermediates/MYAPPNAME.build/Debug-iphoneos/MYAPPNAME.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SDWebImageDownloaderOperation-AD8E43D0E4994A5B.o
    /Users/Daddio/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPPNAME-fpqubbtwwhfsgegevxpimtzqzhqb/Build/Intermediates/MYAPPNAME.build/Debug-iphoneos/MYAPPNAME.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SDWebImageDownloaderOperation-4D62FB959721E071.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SDWebImageDownloaderOperation._connection in:
    /Users/Daddio/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPPNAME-fpqubbtwwhfsgegevxpimtzqzhqb/Build/Intermediates/CloseBuy.build/Debug-iphoneos/MYAPPNAME.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SDWebImageDownloaderOperation-AD8E43D0E4994A5B.o
    /Users/Daddio/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPPNAME-fpqubbtwwhfsgegevxpimtzqzhqb/Build/Intermediates/MYAPPNAME.build/Debug-iphoneos/MYAPPNAME.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SDWebImageDownloaderOperation-4D62FB959721E071.o
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow,I figured it out. I had one mess of a project. Duplicate files all over the place and one by one I had to weed them out. For anyone else trying to understand the log like I have posted above, the key is to look for multiples of the same files which you can tell by the repetitive references to groups/files/code like you see above.

Comment: i have same issue, could you explain more detail ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today - in my case it seemed like the cache got out of whack. I just deleted the `Pods` folder, `.xcworkspace` file and `Podfile.lock` file, and did a fresh `pod install`. After that everything was great again.